# Am I allowed to define both many-to-many and one-to-many relationships between User and Server models in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models called User and Server and my verbal description of their relationships is something like this:

1. A User can create Servers and is therefore their owner. Following this logic, I need to implement a one-to-many relationship between these 2 models. That means the Server should have a userId column which will contain the id of the User/Owner.
2. Users can join many servers and a Server can be joined by many users, so I need to implement many-to-many relationship between these 2 models and have a junction table as well.

So my question is can I apply 2 relationships between the models like this:

```
let User = require('./models/User');
let ServerUser = require('./models/ServerUser');
let Server = require('./models/Server');

User.hasMany(Server)
Server.belongsTo(User)

User.belongsToMany(Server, { through: ServerUser });
Server.belongsToMany(User, { through: ServerUser });
```

What makes me think this won't work is this - once a relationship is created, Sequelize offers you some magic methods which you can use. For example in my case I have this:

```
let name = req.body.name;
let thumbnail = req.body.image;
let userId = req.body.userId

let user = await User.findByPk(userId)

let socketServer = await Server.create({
    name: name,
    thumbnail: thumbnail
});

user.addServer(socketServer)
```

Since I've defined a relationship between User and Server, I can use addServer() which does one of two things depending on whether the relationship between the models is one-to-many or many-to-many.

1. If I've defined many-to-many relationship, executing `user.addServer(socketServer)` will create a record in the junction table that will link the userId and serverId.
2. If I've defined one-to-many relationship, executing `user.addServer(socketServer)` will update the userId column of the server to the id of user

So now that I've applied both relationships between the models, when I execute `user.addServer(socketServer)`, I only update the userId column of the server with the id of the user BUT I don't get a record in the junction table that creates the many-to-many relationship.

This leads me to believe I can only use one relationship at a time but how am I to achieve what I'm trying to achieve without the 2 relationships?

Answer (score 0):

## opinion

Your logic you addressed seems to me that User creates server and user within the server creates server on and on. Is the consequence correct?

shouldn't the one user create servers and other users go in to the servers

my suggetion is create one to many among user and server and have privillage table so the one user created the server have the authority to the what ever he or she wants.